# Real time schedulers in Linux

Tags: linux, scheduler

Why, in Linux, the **sched_fifo** and the **sched_rr** are called real-time schedulers, while **sched_other** is called non real-time scheduler ?

Answer (score 0):

The term "real-time" when it comes to schedulers is used to denote if that scheduler can mathematically guarantee that within certain parameters all the periodic tasks within the system will meet their deadlines. This is important in things like closed loop control.

The problem with the Linux kernel is that even if you are using a real-time scheduler you do not have the guarantee that you will meet deadlines because of things like spin locks in the kernel itself. If you want true hard real-time you have to not only use a real-time scheduler but have to use the real-time patches as of this writing. In the future it is intended by some in the community that those patches be put into the mainline kernel.

Answer (score 0):

**The scheduler** is the kernel component that decides which runnable thread will be executed by the CPU next.  Each thread has an associated scheduling policy and a *static* scheduling priority, *sched_priority*.  The scheduler makes its decisions based on knowledge of the scheduling policy and static priority of all threads on the system.

For threads scheduled under one of the normal scheduling policies **(SCHED_OTHER, SCHED_IDLE, SCHED_BATCH)**, *sched_priority* is not used in scheduling decisions (it must be specified as 0).

Processes scheduled under one of the real-time policies **(SCHED_FIFO, SCHED_RR)** have a *sched_priority* value in the range 1 (low) to 99(high). (As the numbers imply, real-time threads always have higher priority than normal threads.)